# Problem with counter_cache implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I'm getting 'rake aborted! ... posts_count is marked readonly' errors.

I have two models: user and post.

```
users has_many posts.

posts belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
```

I have a migration which adds the posts_count column to the users table and then calculates and records the current number of posts per user.

```
self.up
  add_column :users, :posts_count, :integer, :default => 0

  User.reset_column_information
  User.all.each do |u|
    u.update_attribute( :posts_count, u.posts.count)
  end
end
```

when I run the migration I get the error. This is pretty clear-cut, of course and if I remove the :counter_cache declaration from the posts model, e.g.

```
belongs_to :user
```

the migration runs fine. This obviously, does not make sense because you couldn't really implement it this way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should be using `User.reset_counters` to do this. Additionally, I would recommend using `find_each` instead of `each` because it will iterate the collection in batches instead of all at once.

```
self.up
  add_column :users, :posts_count, :integer, :default => 0

  User.reset_column_information
  User.find_each do |u|
    User.reset_counters u.id, :posts
  end
end
```

Comment: It appears that the preferred approach is: "User.reset_counters u.id, :posts_count".  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html

Comment: Slight correction to above (not able to edit that comment any more): "User.reset_counters u.id, :posts"

Comment: @Mike Fischer good catch, looks like `reset_counters` uses fewer SQL calls.

Comment: @gwho I don't see any deprecation notice on either method in either `4-1-stable` or `master`. What makes you think that? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb

Comment: apidock said that. And it wasn't working for me. i'm mistaken

Comment: @gwho apidock calls anything "deprecated" if the code moves locations. I generally avoid that site, it is often confusing like that.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the documentation states:

> Counter cache columns are added to the
>   containing model’s list of read-only
>   attributes through attr_readonly.

I think this is what happens: you declare the counter in the model's definition, thus rendering the "posts_count" attribute read-only. Then, in the migration, you attempt to update it directly, resulting in the error you mention.

The quick-and-dirty solution is to remove the counter_cache declaration from the model, run the migration (in order to add the required column to the database AND populate it with the current post counts), and then re-add the counter_cache declaration to the model. Should work but is nasty and requires manual intervention during the migration - not a good idea.

I found [this blog post](http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/30194408/updating-counter-cache-in-migrations) which suggests altering the model's list of read-only attributes during the migration, it's a bit oudated but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am using the workaround you suggested, but as you agree, it is not a good way to get things into production. Thanks also for the blog article, but that hack doesn't seem to work anymore (I am using rails 3.0.1 currently.) I may just have to roll my own cache counters and maintain them in the app.

Comment: That blog post is misleading or outdated. See [this one](http://josh.the-owens.com/rails-edge-change-how-to-add-a-counter-cache).

Comment: This was the problem for me. `counter_cache: true` was setting doing some behind the scene `attr_readonly` magic behind the scenes and blocking my migration

Comment: This way poses a problem when trying to do it on a remote repository like heroku. Upload a version with countercache off, then migrate, then upload a verson with countercache implemented? ew.