# Why do I get this error if I try to make counter cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, counter-cache

I'm using `Rails 3.2.6`.  When I try to make **counter cache**, I get this error somehow.
How can I fix this? I've done the same thing on this app but not on this model.
What's wrong with my code or association?

**command**  `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

**Log**

```
==  AddCommunityTopicsCountToCommunity: migrating =============================
-- add_column(:communities, :community_topics_count, :integer, {:default=>0})
   -> 0.0635s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

community_topics_count is marked as readonly
```

**models/community.rb**

```
...
has_many :community_topics
...
```

**models/community_topic.rb**

```
...
belongs_to :community, counter_cache: true
...
```

**migration file**

```
class AddCommunityTopicsCountToCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :communities, :community_topics_count, :integer, :default => 0

    Community.reset_column_information
    Community.all.each do |p|
      p.update_attribute :community_topics_count, p.community_topics.length
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :communities, :community_topics_count
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with counter\_cache implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295404/problem-with-counter-cache-implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class AddCommunityTopicsCountToCommunity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :communities, :community_topics_count, :integer, :default => 0

    Community.reset_column_information
    Community.all.each do |c|
      Community.reset_counters(c.id, :community_topics)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @EvgenlyRyzhkov Thanks for the perfect answer. I wonder why I could implement counter cache by the same way to the other model, which was created automatically by the gem `acts_as_commentable` and it's parent model.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a `conter_cache`, it's not possible to updated it using Rails set it as read-only by default.

You can bypass this by replacing `updated_attribute` with `update_column`, which skips any validation or callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

`conter_cache` has its own methods to deal with, check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html) for details.

In your case you can use something like

```
Community.all.each do |p|
  Community.reset_counters(p.id, :community_topics)
end
```

Comment: so something like this? `Community.reset_counters(p.id, :community_topics => , p.community_topics.length)`

Comment: No, no needs to explicitly set counter value, just id and counter name. It's smart enough to construct correct SQL query and update record.